# Were weapons allowed in Carpenters Hall during the first and second continental Congresses?

Tags: united-states, 18th-century

During the founding of the nation, what restrictions were in place at public forums related to the carrying of weapons (fire arms, knives, small caliber pistols, etc.), especially during the Continental Congresses and the writing of the Articles of Confederation and the Constitution ?

Comment: [Please document your preliminary research](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786). H:SE has multiple answers about the period between the Articles & the Constitution (IIRC, all legislative actions are published and there are no weapons restriction, although Pennsylvania &/or Philadelphia may have had some).  During the first Continental Congress, British common law would probably have applied, and I believe [Blackstone's](https://www.google.com/search?q=blackstone%27s+commentaries+pdf) is available online.